# Running a file inside a folder that contains string in autohotkey

Tags: regex, autohotkey

I need to run a file inside a folder that always changes a version.
I tried Run "E:\Test.*\TestScript.exe"
While Test.* is physically Testv1.22
But obviously I need a regex command to run it and i have no idea how to do that.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Spyre If it wasn't for your comment I would have downvoted too - it doesn't make sense without that context...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first looped through all of the exes in the directory provided (`E:\Test\`).

Next, I used [`RegExMatch`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/RegExMatch.htm) on the current file name of the current iteration of the loop as the haystack, and `Testv.*Script.exe` as the needle.

This needle will allow for file names of the format `"Testv"+[any combination of characters]+"Script.exe"` to be accepted as matches.

If it gets a match, then I run the full path of the current file, launching the exe.

---

Final code:

```
Loop, Files, E:\Test\*.exe
{
    ;MsgBox %A_LoopFileName% ;uncomment to see the file currently being iterated
    if(RegExMatch(A_LoopFileName, "Testv.*Script.exe")){
        run %A_LoopFilePath%
    }
}
```